# {% extends "" %} causing Django to ignore other code in file

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm developing a website using the Django framework. I want to use one file (base.html) to establish a header and footer on every page. I have done this, but Django is now ignoring the code that's already in the other html files.

This is the code for frontpage.html. I'm intending for the code below to use the code from both base.html and frontpage.html, but it's only using the code from base.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
    <p>Example</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I didn't get the intended result. "extends" should have been "include". "Extends" appears to overwrite the code that's already in the file, while "include" appears to include the code from the other file in this one.

Comment: `extends` won't overwrite if you code `{{block.super}}` in the extension of the parent block. This lets you prepend and append extra content to the default in the base or other template.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed you might be having some trouble with Django template inheritance.  i think that the probleme is that you forgot the block tags ,make sure to use them .

Here's an example:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <!-- your code -->
{% endblock %}
```

for more details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/language/